# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError Mapper Mapper[Supplier(supplier)] could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'supplier'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

```
class Supplier(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'supplier'

    # Explicitly mark this column as the primary key
    supplier_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    supplier_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    currency = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    # One to Many relationship

    products = db.relationship('Products', backref='supplier', lazy='dynamic')


class Products(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    supplier_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('supplier.supplier_id'))
    product_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    product_category = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    product_vertical = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    ean_code = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    color = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    power = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    label = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    packing = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)        
    unit_price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    currency = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    # One to One relationship
    suppliers= db.relationship('Supplier', backref='products', uselist=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Product name is {self.product_name} product_id is {self.id} and supplier is {self.supplier.name}, supplier_id is {self.supplier.supplier_id} and quantity is {self.qty}"





class PurchaseOrder(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'purchase_order'

    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    serial_number = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    supplier_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('supplier.supplier_id'))
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id'))
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    unit_price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    net_price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    total = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)

    # One to Many
    suppliers = db.relationship('Supplier', backref='PurchaseOrder', lazy='dynamic')
    products = db.relationship('Products', backref='PurchaseOrder', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<PurchaseOrder {self.order_id}>
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\Imports> Flask db init
C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\Imports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 1064, in main
    cli.main()
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1682, in invoke
    cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1729, in resolve_command
    cmd = self.get_command(ctx, cmd_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 579, in get_command
    app = info.load_app()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 313, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 219, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\Imports\app.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Supplier(db.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(name, bases, d, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 144, in __init__
    super().__init__(name, bases, d, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_api.py", line 196, in __init__
    _as_declarative(reg, cls, dict_)
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 247, in _as_declarative
    return _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(registry, cls, dict_, None, {})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 328, in setup_mapping
    return _ClassScanMapperConfig(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 582, in __init__
    self._early_mapping(mapper_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 369, in _early_mapping
    self.map(mapper_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 1957, in map
    mapper_cls(self.cls, self.local_table, **self.mapper_args),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 281, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 853, in __init__
    self._configure_pks()
  File "C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\flask_venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 1637, in _configure_pks
    raise sa_exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper[Supplier(supplier)] could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'supplier'
PS C:\Users\Wishes Lawrence\Desktop\lace-data1\Desktop\Import_Export_Software_Flask\Imports
```

> 

Comment: It might just be because you've got `supplier` in your `Supplier.products` backref relationship but `Products.suppliers` as your relationship i.e. your relationship and the backref don't match 'suppliers' != 'supplier'.